# oracle Sql query to get the Attribute value , where the whole xml is stored in the CLOB datatype in a table

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, attributes

```
    <note>
  <date>
    <day>12</day>
    <month>11</month>
    <year>2002</year>
  </date>
  <to>Tall</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

The above xml is stored in CLOB datatype, we have to get the value of Attribute heading and year.
The answer should be - Reminder /2002
How to do this using oracle sql query.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `XMLTABLE`:

```sql
SELECT heading || '/' || year AS heading_and_year
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY XMLTABLE(
         '/note'
         PASSING XMLTYPE(t.value)
         COLUMNS
           year    NUMBER(4,0) PATH './date/year',
           heading VARCHAR2(20) PATH './heading'
       ) x
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value CLOB );

INSERT INTO table_name (
  value
) VALUES (
'<note>
  <date>
    <day>12</day>
    <month>11</month>
    <year>2002</year>
  </date>
  <to>Tall</to>
  <from>Jani</from>
  <heading>Reminder</heading>
  <body>Don''t forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>'
);
```

Outputs:

> | HEADING_AND_YEAR |
> | --- |
> | Reminder/2002 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=10271e1a9fe92bc4d21574d520d2c633)*